# how to configure Nifi 1.15.2 to use HTTP without authentication

Tags: apache-nifi

Nifi v1.15.2 use https and authentication by default whereas it was not the case for older version of Nifi for example v1.13.2.
I want to configure nifi v1.15.2 using http and without authentication 
I think i have to modify one of these properties but i don't really know which ones
below the initial configuration

```
# web properties #
#############################################

# For security, NiFi will present the UI on 127.0.0.1 and only be accessible through this loopback interface.
# Be aware that changing these properties may affect how your instance can be accessed without any restriction.
# We recommend configuring HTTPS instead. The administrators guide provides instructions on how to do this.

nifi.web.http.host=
nifi.web.http.port=
nifi.web.http.network.interface.default=

#############################################

nifi.web.https.host=127.0.0.1
nifi.web.https.port=8443
nifi.web.https.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200
nifi.web.max.header.size=16 KB
nifi.web.proxy.context.path=
nifi.web.proxy.host=
nifi.web.max.content.size=
nifi.web.max.requests.per.second=30000
nifi.web.max.access.token.requests.per.second=25
nifi.web.request.timeout=60 secs
nifi.web.request.ip.whitelist=
nifi.web.should.send.server.version=true

# Include or Exclude TLS Cipher Suites for HTTPS
nifi.web.https.ciphersuites.include=
nifi.web.https.ciphersuites.exclude=

# security properties #
nifi.sensitive.props.key=VdY5sz08vgaK7QZ3kfh1jsC0N0bSKK5F
nifi.sensitive.props.key.protected=
nifi.sensitive.props.algorithm=NIFI_PBKDF2_AES_GCM_256
nifi.sensitive.props.additional.keys=

nifi.security.autoreload.enabled=false
nifi.security.autoreload.interval=10 secs
nifi.security.keystore=./conf/keystore.p12
nifi.security.keystoreType=PKCS12
nifi.security.keystorePasswd=63267bec3aac8ab9ef98aac68f49f603
nifi.security.keyPasswd=63267bec3aac8ab9ef98aac68f49f603
nifi.security.truststore=./conf/truststore.p12
nifi.security.truststoreType=PKCS12
nifi.security.truststorePasswd=98d7c94fa28a9ba24a5c7f9c1a8105c6
nifi.security.user.authorizer=single-user-authorizer
nifi.security.allow.anonymous.authentication=false
nifi.security.user.login.identity.provider=single-user-provider
nifi.security.user.jws.key.rotation.period=PT1H
nifi.security.ocsp.responder.url=
nifi.security.ocsp.responder.certificate=
```

I tried to modify like this, i removed value for the key nifi.web.https.host and nifi.web.https.port and  add it to nifi.web.http.host and nifi.web.http.port like this :

```
# For security, NiFi will present the UI on 127.0.0.1 and only be accessible through this loopback interface.
# Be aware that changing these properties may affect how your instance can be accessed without any restriction.
# We recommend configuring HTTPS instead. The administrators guide provides instructions on how to do this.

nifi.web.http.host=localhost
nifi.web.http.port=8080
nifi.web.http.network.interface.default=

#############################################

nifi.web.https.host=
nifi.web.https.port=
nifi.web.https.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200
nifi.web.max.header.size=16 KB
nifi.web.proxy.context.path=
nifi.web.proxy.host=
nifi.web.max.content.size=
nifi.web.max.requests.per.second=30000
nifi.web.max.access.token.requests.per.second=25
nifi.web.request.timeout=60 secs
nifi.web.request.ip.whitelist=
nifi.web.should.send.server.version=true
```

But in log file i got this error

```
2022-01-07 10:33:08,341 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr Failed to start web server: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiWebApiSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setJwtAuthenticationProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.nifi.web.security.configuration.JwtAuthenticationSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 3; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowController': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Remote input HTTPS is enabled but nifi.web.https.port is not specified.
2022-01-07 10:33:08,341 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr Shutting down...
```

Any idea?

Comment: My question would be: why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove authentication, one would need to do what was done for the configuration of NiFi pre-1.14.0, as with 1.14.0 "NiFi now starts up in a mode enabling security features by default.  This means NiFi starts up with HTTPS only now instead of HTTP and it requires a specific auto generated username and password to login or the user can explicitly set the username and password which will be used via the provided toolkit.  Gone are the days of firing a default NiFi and it is accessible via HTTP without authentication." https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Release+Notes#ReleaseNotes-Version1.14.0

Of course, the values of "nifi.web.http.host= and nifi.web.http.port=" need to be set. I would also consider changing the keystore and truststore values, plus nifi.security.user.authorizer as well to blank.

If this all doesnt work, what I would recommend is downloading Nifi 1.13.2 and trying to see if using the nifi.properties that it has by default will work in NiFi 1.15.2. This is the best start.

If this answer has assisted you in solving the issue, please feel free to accept this answer as the solution.

Comment: this does not work :( in fact the goal is to use nifi version greater than 15 becaseu of the log4j vulnerability

Comment: So did you copy the NiFi.properties from a version that doesn’t have authentication turned on by default and used it for the newest version?

Comment: Yep, need also to copy new properties from new version to the old version, and it work, thanks :)

Comment: @coolguy2021, can you please post the properties that worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

@mherzog

this is the config set in my nifi.properties file that worked for me, replace the content of the nifi.properties conf with this one below

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# Core Properties #
nifi.flow.configuration.file=./conf/flow.xml.gz
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.enabled=true
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.dir=./conf/archive/
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.max.time=30 days
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.max.storage=500 MB
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.max.count=
nifi.flowcontroller.autoResumeState=true
nifi.flowcontroller.graceful.shutdown.period=10 sec
nifi.flowservice.writedelay.interval=500 ms
nifi.administrative.yield.duration=30 sec
# If a component has no work to do (is "bored"), how long should we wait before checking again for work?
nifi.bored.yield.duration=10 millis
nifi.queue.backpressure.count=10000
nifi.queue.backpressure.size=1 GB

nifi.authorizer.configuration.file=./conf/authorizers.xml
nifi.login.identity.provider.configuration.file=./conf/login-identity-providers.xml
nifi.templates.directory=./conf/templates
nifi.ui.banner.text=
nifi.ui.autorefresh.interval=30 sec
nifi.nar.library.directory=./lib
nifi.nar.library.autoload.directory=./extensions
nifi.nar.working.directory=./work/nar/
nifi.documentation.working.directory=./work/docs/components

####################
# State Management #
####################
nifi.state.management.configuration.file=./conf/state-management.xml
# The ID of the local state provider
nifi.state.management.provider.local=local-provider
# The ID of the cluster-wide state provider. This will be ignored if NiFi is not clustered but must be populated if running in a cluster.
nifi.state.management.provider.cluster=zk-provider
# Specifies whether or not this instance of NiFi should run an embedded ZooKeeper server
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start=false
# Properties file that provides the ZooKeeper properties to use if <nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start> is set to true
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.properties=./conf/zookeeper.properties


# H2 Settings
nifi.database.directory=./database_repository
nifi.h2.url.append=;LOCK_TIMEOUT=25000;WRITE_DELAY=0;AUTO_SERVER=FALSE

# FlowFile Repository
nifi.flowfile.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository
nifi.flowfile.repository.wal.implementation=org.apache.nifi.wali.SequentialAccessWriteAheadLog
nifi.flowfile.repository.directory=./flowfile_repository
nifi.flowfile.repository.checkpoint.interval=20 secs
nifi.flowfile.repository.always.sync=false
nifi.flowfile.repository.encryption.key.provider.implementation=
nifi.flowfile.repository.encryption.key.provider.location=
nifi.flowfile.repository.encryption.key.id=
nifi.flowfile.repository.encryption.key=
nifi.flowfile.repository.retain.orphaned.flowfiles=true

nifi.swap.manager.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.FileSystemSwapManager
nifi.queue.swap.threshold=20000

# Content Repository
nifi.content.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.FileSystemRepository
nifi.content.claim.max.appendable.size=1 MB
nifi.content.repository.directory.default=./content_repository
nifi.content.repository.archive.max.retention.period=7 days
nifi.content.repository.archive.max.usage.percentage=50%
nifi.content.repository.archive.enabled=true
nifi.content.repository.always.sync=false
nifi.content.viewer.url=../nifi-content-viewer/
nifi.content.repository.encryption.key.provider.implementation=
nifi.content.repository.encryption.key.provider.location=
nifi.content.repository.encryption.key.id=
nifi.content.repository.encryption.key=

# Provenance Repository Properties
nifi.provenance.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.provenance.WriteAheadProvenanceRepository
nifi.provenance.repository.encryption.key.provider.implementation=
nifi.provenance.repository.encryption.key.provider.location=
nifi.provenance.repository.encryption.key.id=
nifi.provenance.repository.encryption.key=

# Persistent Provenance Repository Properties
nifi.provenance.repository.directory.default=./provenance_repository
nifi.provenance.repository.max.storage.time=30 days
nifi.provenance.repository.max.storage.size=10 GB
nifi.provenance.repository.rollover.time=10 mins
nifi.provenance.repository.rollover.size=100 MB
nifi.provenance.repository.query.threads=2
nifi.provenance.repository.index.threads=2
nifi.provenance.repository.compress.on.rollover=true
nifi.provenance.repository.always.sync=false
# Comma-separated list of fields. Fields that are not indexed will not be searchable. Valid fields are:
# EventType, FlowFileUUID, Filename, TransitURI, ProcessorID, AlternateIdentifierURI, Relationship, Details
nifi.provenance.repository.indexed.fields=EventType, FlowFileUUID, Filename, ProcessorID, Relationship
# FlowFile Attributes that should be indexed and made searchable.  Some examples to consider are filename, uuid, mime.type
nifi.provenance.repository.indexed.attributes=
# Large values for the shard size will result in more Java heap usage when searching the Provenance Repository
# but should provide better performance
nifi.provenance.repository.index.shard.size=500 MB
# Indicates the maximum length that a FlowFile attribute can be when retrieving a Provenance Event from
# the repository. If the length of any attribute exceeds this value, it will be truncated when the event is retrieved.
nifi.provenance.repository.max.attribute.length=65536
nifi.provenance.repository.concurrent.merge.threads=2


# Volatile Provenance Respository Properties
nifi.provenance.repository.buffer.size=100000

# Component Status Repository
nifi.components.status.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.status.history.VolatileComponentStatusRepository
nifi.components.status.repository.buffer.size=1440
nifi.components.status.snapshot.frequency=1 min

# Site to Site properties
nifi.remote.input.host=
nifi.remote.input.secure=false
nifi.remote.input.socket.port=1026
nifi.remote.input.http.enabled=true
nifi.remote.input.http.transaction.ttl=30 sec
nifi.remote.contents.cache.expiration=30 secs

# web properties #
#############################################

# For security, NiFi will present the UI on 127.0.0.1 and only be accessible through this loopback interface.
# Be aware that changing these properties may affect how your instance can be accessed without any restriction.
# We recommend configuring HTTPS instead. The administrators guide provides instructions on how to do this.

nifi.web.http.host=0.0.0.0
nifi.web.http.port=8080
nifi.web.http.network.interface.default=

#############################################

nifi.web.https.host=
nifi.web.https.port=
nifi.web.https.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200
nifi.web.max.header.size=16 KB
nifi.web.proxy.context.path=
nifi.web.proxy.host=
nifi.web.max.content.size=
nifi.web.max.requests.per.second=30000
nifi.web.max.access.token.requests.per.second=25
nifi.web.request.timeout=60 secs
nifi.web.request.ip.whitelist=
nifi.web.should.send.server.version=true

# Include or Exclude TLS Cipher Suites for HTTPS
nifi.web.https.ciphersuites.include=
nifi.web.https.ciphersuites.exclude=

# security properties #
nifi.sensitive.props.key=l5bGW7Miy5Vv5sGTr8tXqLyVfpOdTnY0
nifi.sensitive.props.key.protected=
nifi.sensitive.props.algorithm=PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
nifi.sensitive.props.provider=BC
nifi.sensitive.props.additional.keys=

nifi.security.keystore=
nifi.security.keystoreType=
nifi.security.keystorePasswd=
nifi.security.keyPasswd=
nifi.security.truststore=
nifi.security.truststoreType=
nifi.security.truststorePasswd=
nifi.security.user.authorizer=managed-authorizer
nifi.security.allow.anonymous.authentication=false
nifi.security.user.login.identity.provider=
nifi.security.ocsp.responder.url=
nifi.security.ocsp.responder.certificate=

# OpenId Connect SSO Properties #
nifi.security.user.oidc.discovery.url=
nifi.security.user.oidc.connect.timeout=5 secs
nifi.security.user.oidc.read.timeout=5 secs
nifi.security.user.oidc.client.id=
nifi.security.user.oidc.client.secret=
nifi.security.user.oidc.preferred.jwsalgorithm=
nifi.security.user.oidc.additional.scopes=
nifi.security.user.oidc.claim.identifying.user=
nifi.security.user.oidc.fallback.claims.identifying.user=

# Apache Knox SSO Properties #
nifi.security.user.knox.url=
nifi.security.user.knox.publicKey=
nifi.security.user.knox.cookieName=hadoop-jwt
nifi.security.user.knox.audiences=

# SAML Properties #
nifi.security.user.saml.idp.metadata.url=
nifi.security.user.saml.sp.entity.id=
nifi.security.user.saml.identity.attribute.name=
nifi.security.user.saml.group.attribute.name=
nifi.security.user.saml.metadata.signing.enabled=false
nifi.security.user.saml.request.signing.enabled=false
nifi.security.user.saml.want.assertions.signed=true
nifi.security.user.saml.signature.algorithm=http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256
nifi.security.user.saml.signature.digest.algorithm=http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256
nifi.security.user.saml.message.logging.enabled=false
nifi.security.user.saml.authentication.expiration=12 hours
nifi.security.user.saml.single.logout.enabled=false
nifi.security.user.saml.http.client.truststore.strategy=JDK
nifi.security.user.saml.http.client.connect.timeout=30 secs
nifi.security.user.saml.http.client.read.timeout=30 secs

# Identity Mapping Properties #
# These properties allow normalizing user identities such that identities coming from different identity providers
# (certificates, LDAP, Kerberos) can be treated the same internally in NiFi. The following example demonstrates normalizing
# DNs from certificates and principals from Kerberos into a common identity string:
#
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.pattern.dn=^CN=(.*?), OU=(.*?), O=(.*?), L=(.*?), ST=(.*?), C=(.*?)$
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.value.dn=$1@$2
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.transform.dn=NONE
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.pattern.kerb=^(.*?)/instance@(.*?)$
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.value.kerb=$1@$2
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.transform.kerb=UPPER

# Group Mapping Properties #
# These properties allow normalizing group names coming from external sources like LDAP. The following example
# lowercases any group name.
#
# nifi.security.group.mapping.pattern.anygroup=^(.*)$
# nifi.security.group.mapping.value.anygroup=$1
# nifi.security.group.mapping.transform.anygroup=LOWER

# cluster common properties (all nodes must have same values) #
nifi.cluster.protocol.heartbeat.interval=5 sec
nifi.cluster.protocol.heartbeat.missable.max=8
nifi.cluster.protocol.is.secure=false

# cluster node properties (only configure for cluster nodes) #
nifi.cluster.is.node=false
nifi.cluster.node.address=
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.port=
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.threads=10
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.max.threads=50
nifi.cluster.node.event.history.size=25
nifi.cluster.node.connection.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.read.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.max.concurrent.requests=100
nifi.cluster.firewall.file=
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.wait.time=5 mins
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.candidates=

# cluster load balancing properties #
nifi.cluster.load.balance.host=
nifi.cluster.load.balance.port=6342
nifi.cluster.load.balance.connections.per.node=1
nifi.cluster.load.balance.max.thread.count=8
nifi.cluster.load.balance.comms.timeout=30 sec

# zookeeper properties, used for cluster management #
nifi.zookeeper.connect.string=
nifi.zookeeper.connect.timeout=10 secs
nifi.zookeeper.session.timeout=10 secs
nifi.zookeeper.root.node=/nifi
nifi.zookeeper.client.secure=false
nifi.zookeeper.security.keystore=
nifi.zookeeper.security.keystoreType=
nifi.zookeeper.security.keystorePasswd=
nifi.zookeeper.security.truststore=
nifi.zookeeper.security.truststoreType=
nifi.zookeeper.security.truststorePasswd=

# Zookeeper properties for the authentication scheme used when creating acls on znodes used for cluster management
# Values supported for nifi.zookeeper.auth.type are "default", which will apply world/anyone rights on znodes
# and "sasl" which will give rights to the sasl/kerberos identity used to authenticate the nifi node
# The identity is determined using the value in nifi.kerberos.service.principal and the removeHostFromPrincipal
# and removeRealmFromPrincipal values (which should align with the kerberos.removeHostFromPrincipal and kerberos.removeRealmFromPrincipal
# values configured on the zookeeper server).
nifi.zookeeper.auth.type=
nifi.zookeeper.kerberos.removeHostFromPrincipal=
nifi.zookeeper.kerberos.removeRealmFromPrincipal=

# kerberos #
nifi.kerberos.krb5.file=

# kerberos service principal #
nifi.kerberos.service.principal=
nifi.kerberos.service.keytab.location=

# kerberos spnego principal #
nifi.kerberos.spnego.principal=
nifi.kerberos.spnego.keytab.location=
nifi.kerberos.spnego.authentication.expiration=12 hours

# external properties files for variable registry
# supports a comma delimited list of file locations
nifi.variable.registry.properties=

# analytics properties #
nifi.analytics.predict.enabled=false
nifi.analytics.predict.interval=3 mins
nifi.analytics.query.interval=5 mins
nifi.analytics.connection.model.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.status.analytics.models.OrdinaryLeastSquares
nifi.analytics.connection.model.score.name=rSquared
nifi.analytics.connection.model.score.threshold=.90

# runtime monitoring properties
nifi.monitor.long.running.task.schedule=
nifi.monitor.long.running.task.threshold=

# Create automatic diagnostics when stopping/restarting NiFi.

# Enable automatic diagnostic at shutdown.
nifi.diagnostics.on.shutdown.enabled=false

# Include verbose diagnostic information.
nifi.diagnostics.on.shutdown.verbose=false

# The location of the diagnostics folder.
nifi.diagnostics.on.shutdown.directory=./diagnostics

# The maximum number of files permitted in the directory. If the limit is exceeded, the oldest files are deleted.
nifi.diagnostics.on.shutdown.max.filecount=10

# The diagnostics folder's maximum permitted size in bytes. If the limit is exceeded, the oldest files are deleted.
nifi.diagnostics.on.shutdown.max.directory.size=10 MB
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since I had to go through this, as well, I wanted to share the entries in `nifi.properties` that allowed me to run NiFi 1.19.1 in a docker container without the config substitution trying to enable HTTPS during the startup sequence.  These are ONLY the properties that concern this issue, so make sure that this is not the only content in your `nifi.properties` file:

```
nifi.web.http.host=0.0.0.0
nifi.web.http.port=8080
nifi.web.https.host=
nifi.web.https.port=
nifi.security.keystore=
nifi.security.keystoreType=
nifi.security.keystorePasswd=
nifi.security.keyPasswd=
nifi.security.truststore=
nifi.security.truststoreType=
nifi.security.truststorePasswd=
```

For Docker containers, it looks like you also need to set a couple of environment variables:

```
--env "NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT=<your container port>"
--env "NIFI_WEB_HTTP_HOST=<your container hostname>"
```

After trying to bring up NiFi with the blank properties commented out, I realized that will not work.  So, ensure that you do not comment the blank properties, but include them *empty*.

Answer (score 0):

#modify conf/nifi.properties

```
before - nifi.remote.input.secure=true
after  - nifi.remote.input.secure=false
```

#last modify content

```
nifi.web.http.host=0.0.0.0
nifi.web.http.port=8543 #modify to your port
```

Empty the value

```
nifi.web.https.host=
nifi.web.https.port=
```